# Selector for SystemStatusBar::NSStatusItem is unrecognized

Tags: cocoa, swift, selector, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I am trying to receive an event when the `NSStatusItem` is clicked (Action is performed). However, this is what I see in the console (the application does not crash) - **unrecognized selector sent to instance**

```
2014-11-14 00:42:29.565 T1[90662:303] -[NSSystemStatusBar somethingHappened]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000008c990
2014-11-14 00:42:29.573 T1[90662:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation  
. . .
```

This is the code that I am trying to work with:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
    var statusBar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar();
    var statusBarItem : NSStatusItem! = NSStatusItem();
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {   
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItemWithLength(-1)
        statusBarItem.target = self
        statusBarItem.action = Selector("somethingHappened");
        statusBarItem.menu = nil;
    }
    @IBAction func somethingHappened(sender: NSStatusItem)
    {
        println("Hello from StatusItem");
    }
}
```

In order to understand what is going wrong with this, I've translated a couple of exactly similar Objective-C tutorials to Swift, but there seems to be something that I am missing but not able to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
statusBarItem.target = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
statusBarItem.action = Selector("somethingHappened")
```

should be

```
statusBarItem.target = self
statusBarItem.action = Selector("somethingHappened:");
```

The action target is the `AppDelegate` instance, and the selector "somethingHappened:"
(with the colon) because the method takes one argument.

For **Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3** it is

```
statusBarItem.action = #selector(somethingHappened(_:));
```

Comment: I swear I did that and it continued to fail. Perhaps I was doing something wrong somewhere else. But it works now. Thank you.